# call newinstance with startactivitywithresult

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

this is how I call my DialogFragment

```
IncomeAdd dfIncomeAdd = IncomeAdd.newInstance(currentYear,currentMonth);
dfIncomeAdd.setTargetFragment(this, Activity.RESULT_OK);
dfIncomeAdd.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
```

and I need the DialogFragment to return it's result to my calling fragment, so I use onActivityResult but it seems onActivityResult isn't being triggered. I read somewhere that I need to start the DialogFragment activity by calling it with StartActivityForResult. But how do I call StartActivityForResult when using newInstance?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to call onActivityResult.
You can just create a method in your Activity class, say:

```
dialogListener(String... args)      //data to be sent from dialog will go in as arguments, that's a var-arg syntax
{
   //write code which you intented to write in onActivityResult
}
```

call this method while you dismiss the dialog.

Comment: ok understood, but how do I pass some value to the caller fragment?

Comment: you mean value from the dialog? you can pass it as an argument to that dialogListener method you would be calling

Comment: sorry I still couldn't see it.. could u provide a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following pattern. First create dialog listener:

```
public class IncomeAdd extends DialogFragment {
  public interface OnSomethingChanged {
      public void onChange(int value);
  }

  OnSomethingChanged mListener;

  public void setListener(OnSomethingChanged l) {
      mListener = l;
  }
}
```

Now you should call `mListener.onChange(dialogValue)` when `OK` button is clicked:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onDateChange(dialogValue);
        }
    }
});
```

Showing dialog:

```
IncomeAdd dfIncomeAdd = IncomeAdd.newInstance(currentYear,currentMonth);
dfIncomeAdd.setListener(new OnSomethingChanged() {

  public void onChange(int value) {
      // do with value what you want
  }

});
dfIncomeAdd.show(getActivity(),"fragmentDialog");
```